# How to do bootstrappingcross-validation on an gamlss model with random effect in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation

I want to do bootstrapping cross-validation of a gamlss model. The explanatory variable (moipro) is of beta distribution so I use the gamlss package instead of lme4 or hglm. This model has a random effect and it is causing troubles.

I tried to use a simplified data set to post my question but it produces different error. So I put the original data instead.

The data is a table which you can download from dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/89852837/sample.csv

When using the formula without random effect, it works.

```
sample<-read.csv("sample.csv",header=T)
library(gamlss)
frml<- moipro ~ Trip + kuse + spp + Water + BwkRain + Trip:spp + BioR:spp + Trip:kuse + Water:Trip

Nruns <- 100
r2_ps <- rep(NA, Nruns)
r_sq <- rep(NA, Nruns)
aic <- rep(NA, Nruns)
data<-sample
N <- dim(data)[1]
for (i in 1:Nruns){
    testSet <- sample(1:N, size = floor(N/2))
    learndata <- data[-testSet,]
    testdata <- data[testSet,]
    cv_mod1 <-gamlss(formula=frml,data=na.omit(learndata), family = BE)
    pred <-predict(cv_mod1,newdata=testdata,type="response")
    r2_ps[i] <- Rsq(cv_mod1,"Cox Snell")
    r_sq[i]<-cor(pred,testdata$moipro)^2
    aic[i] <- cv_mod1$aic
}
Results<- cbind(r2_ps, r_sq, aic)
```

When using formula with random effect, error appears for the "prediction":

```
sample<-read.csv("sample.csv",header=T)
library(gamlss)
frml1_re<- moipro ~ Trip + kuse + spp + Water + BwkRain + Trip:spp + BioR:spp + Trip:kuse + Water:Trip+re(random=~1|Site)

Nruns <- 100
r2_ps <- rep(NA, Nruns)
r_sq <- rep(NA, Nruns)
aic <- rep(NA, Nruns)
data<-sample
N <- dim(data)[1]
for (i in 1:Nruns){
    testSet <- sample(1:N, size = floor(N/2))
    learndata <- data[-testSet,]
    testdata <- data[testSet,]
    cv_mod1 <-gamlss(formula=frml_re,data=na.omit(learndata), family = BE)
    pred <-predict(cv_mod1,newdata=testdata,type="response")
    r2_ps[i] <- Rsq(cv_mod1,"Cox Snell")
    r_sq[i]<-cor(pred,testdata$moipro)^2
    aic[i] <- cv_mod1$aic
}      
new prediction
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'fix.formula' not found
```

How can I apply cross-validation on my model? Any help is appreciated! Many thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're missing a data object and a library call for this to be a reproducible example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Generally one describes a link for the regression "response" and then uses an error distribution for statistical inference. The default link for the `betareg` function and for the 'BE' family for `gamlss` is "logit". I'm guessing your errors are beta distributed. Cross-validation and bootstrapping are different procedures. I think the degree of confusion in this question makes it more appropriate for CrossValidated.com.

Comment: Thanks Hack-R. I edited the question so that others can duplicate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your correction 42. I'm a newbie and may not have the terminology down correctly. I also posted my question on the website you recommended.